# Inaccessible Ledge in DOOM 2

Tags: doom-2

I’m playing *DOOM 2* and my OCD is forcing me to get 100% kills, items, and secrets, but have run into a problem. I know there are bugs in several maps that make some items and secrets impossible to get, so I am wondering if this is one of them.

On level 20 (“Gotcha!”), there is a tower behind the player’s starting position which contains a ledge that has some items on it, but seems to be impossible to get to.

I checked numerous [FAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/197142-doom-ii/faqs), [guides](http://www.classicdoom.com/maps/d2secs/20.htm), and [walkthroughs](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/MAP20:_Gotcha!_%28Doom_II%29) but none of them mention this ledge. I even opened the level in an editor and found that it has no trigger ID associated with the sector, so it does not seem that it can be lowered, nor does it have a transport destination on it. I cannot figure out *any* way to get up there (I considered rocket-jumping, but that is not really possible in this instance, and I doubt that was the intent anyway).

**Figure 1**: The ledge in first-person—mode

[image]

**Figure 2**: The ledge in map-mode

[image]

**Figure 3**: The items on the ledge

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It [turns out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FA6LWSDFYI) that you have to use the door to the tower—the wood-paneled wall to the left of the screenshot. (I didn’t even notice that it doesn’t close all the way because the top is not visible.)

You have to open the door, stand on it, then wait for it rise, taking you up along with it, and then run across the gap.

Comment: Hmm, it happened again. A couple of levels ago, I came across another instance of having to use a door to get to an inaccessible area. I almost checked the Internet when I couldn’t figure out how to get to it, but fortunately this was still fresh in my mind. It is odd that id made an area that requires what essentially feels like an exploit of sorts (like rocket-jumping to areas not designed to be reached). Moreover, that it did not come up until after 56 levels (36 in DOOM 1 and 20 in DOOM 2), it feels even more like it is an unofficial method.

Comment: This is the map where you can let a Cyberdemon fight vs a Spider Mastermind, isn't it? I loved it :) As to the door, it is very long ago I played it, but in my memory it never felt like a glitch... Everything what moves down to ground floor, can be climed before it raises up again; to me those things were always lifts, even if they are designed as a door like in your example.

Comment: `in my memory it never felt like a glitch... Everything what moves down to ground floor, can be climed before it raises up again; to me those things were always lifts, even if they are designed as a door like in your example`   @Desty, yes, but using a door as a lift was never done in any level in D1 or D2 until here, so using it as such would have been “playing outside the box”. Moreover, most doors in the game had always been embedded into walls, making them impossible to get on top of, further making it not something most people would think of.

Comment: @Synetech That's why you are rewarded for working it out.

Comment: You can't see the top of the "door" from inside the room, but you can see it through the window when you turn around from the starting point. And as @Desty mentioned, the fact that this "door" lowers rather than raises is your second hint. Definitely subtle, but I wouldn't put it in the same category as that E3M6 exit...